# How can I set an intent's class from a string value?

Tags: android, string, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to set the class for an intent to the address listed in a string value, so that I can launch a given activity.  The string is composed dynamically during runtime.

Is there anyway to make something like the code below run:

```
String target=com.test.activity1.class;
Intent intent=new intent();
intent.setClass(this, target);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [`forName` method of the `Class` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

Anyway, I've been wondering the use of the [`setClassName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method... it could be useful in your case maybe

Answer (score 0):

Intent class has the method `setClassName`

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(context,target);
```